# How can I network a Windows 7 PC with a MacBook Pro running Lion over FireWire?

Tags: windows-7, networking, osx-lion, firewire

I always thought this was possible but after searching around a little bit all the articles that even come close are using OSes pre Windows 7 and OSX 10.7 (Lion).  I tried just connecting them with a FireWire cable and Windows just reported the MacBook as an unknown device.

Has anyone got this working?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Microsoft [dropped "1394" networking with Vista](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943719) (maybe even with XP-SP3). The feature is still in Lion though. [ubCore drivers](http://www.unibrain.com/products/driverapi/ubcore.htm) advertise this feature, but in my brief search I only saw claims they did not work.

If it's a one-off, you might be able to boot Linux on the PC to get it to talk to the Mac.

You might have better luck with direct-connect Ethernet with a crossover cable (or maybe the adapters for the computers will do auto-crossover with a regular cable).

Comment: A crossover cable isn't needed with Mac ethernet ports (unless it's a really old model > 6 years or so).